# 这里的“奠过茶饭”和“大家见过”中的“过”应该读第四声还是轻声？（Is this “过” supposed to be read with the fourth tone, or the neutral tone？）

Tags: tones

Question：

“奠过茶饭”和“大家见过”中的“过”应该读第四声还是轻声？

对于这里的“过”的意义与声调，好像只有两种可能，它们是：

1、表示动作完毕的轻声的“过”

2、表示人或物随动作跨越时空的第四声的“过”

请看其原文：

原来这馒头庵就是水月庵，因他庙里做的馒头好，就起了这个浑号，离铁槛寺不远。当下和尚工课已完，奠过茶饭，贾珍便命贾蓉请凤姐歇息。凤姐见还有几个妯娌陪着女亲，自己便辞了众人，带了宝玉、秦钟往水月庵来。原来秦业年迈多病，不能在此，只命秦钟等待安灵罢了。那秦钟便只跟着凤姐、宝玉，一时到了水月庵，净虚带领智善、智能两个徒弟出来迎接，大家见过。凤姐等来至净室更衣净手毕，因见智能儿越发长高了，模样儿越发出息了，因说道：“你们师徒怎么这些日子也不往我们那里去？”净虚道：“可是这几天都没工夫，因胡老爷府里产了公子，太太送了十两银子来这里，叫请几位师父念三日《血盆经》，忙的没个空儿，就没来请奶奶的安。”

Comment: Both are 4th tone.

Answer (score 1):

表示动作完毕的“过”不一定读轻声，也可以读第四声。见《现代汉语规范词典》“过”字条目。

如果口语说很快就容易成轻声，如果慢慢读书就更可能第四声。很多时候可能是介于两者之间的一个音。你这个例子是古代典范著作，如果比较庄重地朗读，读成第四声合适（但是也不要读太重）。

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, this kind of question is actually very interesting.

Before encountering your question, I have no idea that when I read 奠过茶饭 and 大家见过, I read the 过 as 轻声. So I think you can read them as 轻声 too.

Comment: “奠过茶饭”中的过字，或者读轻声或者读去声，好像都可以。读去声，“奠过茶饭”有“双手捧着供品伸过去”的意思；读轻声，“奠过茶饭”有“奠茶奠饭的过程刚刚完毕”的意思。这两种意思与前后分句的内容似乎毫无矛盾。其次，我查词以后发现这里的“见过”可能是谦辞，意思与“来访”相似。其中过字要读去声。